# How to redirect to the browser by clicking on the text inside EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Inside EditText you enter the text of the link format. Of all the guides on the Internet, I managed to make only the text clickable. But there is no way to make a redirect to the site, because immediately after clicking on EditText offer to edit the text. Is there any way to make it so that when you click on the text is redirected, and when you click on the remaining space offered to enter text?[image]

I have this solution. It redirects you to the browser when you click it. But the problem is that now I can't enter the text

```
editText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
fb = intent.getStringExtra("fb");
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(fb);
Linkify.addLinks(spannable, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
CharSequence text = TextUtils.concat(spannable, "\u200B");
editText.setText(text);
```

Comment: why do you want to do this way? any specific reason?